# How to make the data downloaded same across all the versions of browsers?

Tags: javascript, html, content-type

I am downloading a file in my java application using jquery.

It is downloading in correct format in IE8 where as Format is getting changed when i am using IE10.

Here is my code, where I am setting hearder.

```
function converthtml() {
    var CustomerID = document.getElementById('customerID').value;
    var ci = document.getElementById("ci").value;
    var strvar;
    strvar = term.textContent || term.innerText;
    strvar = encodeURIComponent(strvar);

    var xmlHttp;
    var xmlHttp;
    var flag = 0;
    if (typeof XMLHttpRequest != "undefined") {
        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    if (xmlHttp == null) {
        alert("Browser does not support XMLHTTP Request");
        return;
    }
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = stateChange2;

    function stateChange2() {
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 || xmlHttp.readyState == "complete") {
            //alert("response : "+xmlHttp.responseText);
            alert("Session value saved successfuly");
        }
    }

    var params = "sessiondata=" + strvar + "&ci=" + ci + "" + "&customerID=" + CustomerID;
    xmlHttp.open("POST", "DownloadSession", true);
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlHttp.send(params);
    // xmlHttp.send("sessiondata="+strvar+"");       
    document.getElementById("downloadSession").disabled = false;

}
```

I suspect the following statement is causing the format change

```
 xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

Kindly suggest me an alternative that keeps content-type same across all the browser versions......

Comment: This isn't jQuery, but I would recommend you to use it instead of `XMLHttpRequest`. It does a lot of things right automatically.

Comment: Indeed, there is no jQuery there. Also, you should provide sample data (pin-pointing what's wrong)